# Shopify - Product filter with parameter

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am looking for custom product filter using my custom Shopify App. I have created an app like structure and which is append to the product [collection template](https://vivid-navas.myshopify.com/collections/all).

How can I pass custom parameters like price, category or product attributes via URL or how it will render the product on the collection page. 
[image]

Thanks,

Navas

Answer (score 0):

If you created an App, you can add a Proxy to it. The Proxy allows Shopify to send secure data to your App via a Javascript call. You get the data from the shop about the product, you filter it, and you return JSON data if you want, to help the front end. Works great. Try it.